# Inserting dynamic instance variables into a ruby sqlite query

Tags: ruby, sqlite, inheritance

I have a problem trying to create a dynamic save method. This method should work for all children of this parent method. I have set the instance variables to be set dynamically using instance_variable_set and a hash. This is my save method as it exists now:

```ruby
def save
  if DB.execute("SELECT id FROM '#{self.class.name.downcase}s' WHERE id = ?", @id).empty?
    DB.execute("INSERT INTO '#{self.class.name.downcase}s' (url, votes, title) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", @url, @votes, @title)
    @id = DB.last_insert_row_id
  else
    DB.execute("UPDATE '#{self.class.name.downcase}s' SET url = ?, votes = ?, title = ? WHERE id = ?", @url, @votes, @title, @id)
  end
end
```

As you can see, the variables currently have a set number (determined by the number of question marks in the query) and set names (determined by the variable names). How do I make it so that it will take any number of instance variables and names and saves them?

Comment: Are you looking for dynamic as in making your function work for any table (essentially making a basic version of ActiveRecord)?